# How can I make my phone number verifiable by Chase Bank?

Tags: united-states, deposits

My friend endorsed his payroll check to me and I used mobile deposit to deposit it into my Chase bank account. (Used to have PNC account and have never had an issue doing this)
The check cleared my account but Chase put a restriction on my account and then closed my account stating that they could not verify the phone number for the person that the checks were made out to. The phone carrier has been called and it has been confirmed that the account and the phone number are in his name and the information is public. But According to Chase his number can not be verified through the application that they use. They will not provide me with what application that is. So how do I get the number verified?

Comment: Maybe have that person step into a Chase branch to verify their identity?

Comment: The headline doesn't seem to match the question. Whose number are they trying to verify? That person should contact the bank and ask how to handle this

Comment: Also, sanity check: how well do you really know this friend, and did they ask you to send them any money after cashing the check? Bouncing checks in exchange for cash is a well known scam; I haven't heard of it being done with something that looked like a payroll check but I can't see anything that would prevent that from being faked too

Answer (score 1):

What they probably want is for you to come into one of their branches with a phone bill for that number, showing you as the subscriber, at the contact address you have given them. And, I'd course, for you to be depositing it into an account at their bank rather than "cashing" it, so they have time to confirm it's a good check before they hand over the actual money.

The risk of bad checks, which may not be detected until days later, is why the "payday loan" folks are almost justified in charging literally obscene interest rates. They are taking a big risk on being able to collect the money back from you if the check bounces or gets cancelled.

And/or, since it's a payroll check, your bank may want proof that the company exists and issued this check to your friend. Maybe it's the company's phone number and address that are not checking out.

Walk into a branch of your bank and/or the bank the check was drawn upon, ask to speak to someone "on the platform" (bank jargon for someone with more database access and authority than a teller), and ask them what the issue is. They should be able to give you an answer fairly quickly.

All we can do is point out possibilities.